# What is the KeyPressFunc in MATLAB Guide?

Tags: matlab

What is the KeyPressFunc function in MATLAB. I cam across it while creating a GUI on GUIDE. 
Does it allot some sort of a function to a key? If so how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an text-edit, this is the function or callback, that is called, when the text-edit is on focus and a Key is pressed.
within this function, you get get acces to the eventdata-structure, that contains a string with the information wich key was pressed:

```
a=eventdata.Key;
```

for exmaple: you want to do something, only when the uparrow was pressed, you can do something like this:

```
if strcmp(a,'uparrow')
    ...do something...
end
```